# Warning: <elementType /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with React, I've added some Bootstrap form and got the error. I know that there is a lot of the same problems but didn't find solution.

```
<Card className="mb-3 border-dark">
            <Card.Header as="h5">Personal Informations</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
              <Form>
                <Form.Row>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} variant="flush">
                    <Form.Label as="h5">Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="elementType">{patient.name}</Form.Control>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} variant="flush">
                    <Form.Label as="h5">Age</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="elementType">{patient.age}</Form.Control>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} variant="flush">
                    <Form.Label as="h5">Sex</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="elementType">{patient.sex}</Form.Control>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} variant="flush">
                    <Form.Label as="h5">Birth</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="elementType">
                      {patient.birth}
                    </Form.Control>
                  </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
              </Form>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
```

Comment: Component name should start with the Uppercase. I think that might be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [read-only, plaintext](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-input-plaintext) version of
`Form.Control`:

- the value must be supplied as `value`, not as a child

```
<Form.Control plaintext readOnly value={patient.name} />>
```

Comment: I don't want to use it as input but as a static text

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use the `plaintext` variant of `Form.Control`.

Comment: I was  trying that but then i get that error " Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`."

Comment: Updated my answer. You must use `value`, not children, to supply the value of the control.

Comment: That's working thanks. I've added disabled instead of readOnly and plaintext and it's also working

Answer (score 0):

The `as` prop is expecting an element, not a type.  If using a standard HTML element, use lowercase.  If using a custom react component of your own construction, it expects an uppercase name, as that is what is required by react for it to know its a custom component and not an existing HTML element.

Comment: So just change to ElementType ?

Comment: Well no...probably @RossAllen's answer is better.  Just get rid of the `as` prop.  `elementType` in the docs is just referring to the type of value that `as` takes.  It should either be astring of the name of a sandard html element, or a react component.  Unless you have a component named `ElementType`, which is not great sematics.